# Sending integer over socket while avoid breaking strict aliasing rule

Tags: c, windows, sockets, integer, winsock

I am attempting to send a integer over the network in C (more specifically, `uint32_t` bytes). I believe I am sending the data correctly, according to other examples and answers on Stack Overflow; however, when receiving the bytes, I am having trouble casting/converting them to `uint32_t` without breaking the `strict aliasing rule`. Here is an example of my inital attempt:

Sender:

```c
uint32_t num = htonl(100);
char* converted_num = (char*)&num;
send(client_sock, converted_num, sizeof(num), 0);
```

Receiver:

```
char buf[8192];
recv(socket, buf, 8192, 0);
uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)&buf);
printf("%d\n", (int)test);
```

While this may appear to work, I have received feedback that the line `uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)&buf);` breaks the strict aliasing rule. Here is my attempt at fixing the strict aliasing violation:

```
char buf[8192];
recv(socket, buf, 8192, 0);
uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)memcpy(&(uint32_t){0}, &buf[0], sizeof(uint32_t)));
printf("%d\n", (int)test);
```

This causes the program to crash, i.e my question is how do I most efficiently avoid violating the strict aliasing rule when transferring a integer over a socket in c (windows).

Comment: Minor tidbit: when passing an array size to a function, try to derive it with `sizeof` to avoid typing the same magic number (8192) twice: `recv(socket, buf, sizeof buf, 0);`

Comment: Your feedback is wrong -- since the data is written with a `char` type (not copied from another type), it has no effective type, so automatically gets the effective type used to read it.  No strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @ChrisDodd your feedback is wrong, it is an array of char, for which the effective type thing does not quite work like that. Furthermore the more complete program is likely to have unaligned access too, and those are the real silent killer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The data is written by `recv` so has no effective type.  Per 6.5 ANY TIME you copy data as `char`s, it keeps the same effective type, it does not get an effective type of `char`.  Alignment may be a problem, but has nothing to do with strict aliasing.

Comment: What protocol are you using?  'client_sock' suggests TCP, in which case the code as you have posted is broken anyway.

Comment: @ChrisDodd you should read 6.5p6 again, "The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any." - the exception is that allocated objects do not have an effective type. What you're proposing has far-reaching consequences, now possibly all int pointers everwhere are aliasing *any character array anywhere at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break it into several lines:

```
uint32_t tmp;
memcpy(&tmp, buf + whatever, sizeof tmp);
result = ntohl(tmp);
```

You can make it into an inline function too:

```
static inline uint32_t get_u32(char *from) {
    uint32_t tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp, from, sizeof tmp);
    return ntohl(tmp);
}

...

uint32_t test = get_u32(buf + whatever);
```

Comment: @entry934h I can't see anything wrong with your code, other than it being fugly... maybe you've got a compiler bug with compound literals ... :D

Comment: @user253751 no they are not.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code does not have any problem with strict aliasing -- whoever gave you that feedback is incorrect.  The problem it *does* have is alignment -- there's no guarentee that `char buff[8192];` will be properly aligned for any type other than `char` (though it probably will be).  You can avoid that problem by allocating your buffer with malloc:

```
char *buf = malloc(8192);
```

malloc will always return memory that is suitably allocated for any type.  Then your code

```
recv(socket, buf, 8192, 0);
uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)buf);
printf("%d\n", (int)test);
```

is safe, though you should probably check that malloc succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `char`, use `uint32_t` and drop all casting.  Use correct type to print and proper type returned by `recv()`.

```
//char buf[8192];
uint32_t buf[8192/sizeof(uint32_t)];

//recv(socket, buf, 8192, 0);
ssize_t len = recv(socket, buf, sizeof buf, 0);

if (len != -1) { 
  if (len % sizeof *buf != 0) { ; } // TBD code to handle non-multiples of 32-bits
  len /= sizeof *buf;
  for (ssize_t i = 0; i< len; i++) {
    //uint32_t test = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)&buf);
    //printf("%d\n", (int)test);
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", buf[i]);
  }
}
```